# How can I create a portal template in dotnetnuke that keeps each third party modules' settings

Tags: templates, portal, dotnetnuke

I am developing Dotnetnuke (05.06.01) site which will have ~200 portals in it, while the portals are created, they will be produced from prepared four portal templates. 
The problem arises at that point. I have some **3rd party modules** and when i created portal template file their settings are **not set in portal template**.  How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2):

That's strange.  Module and Tab Module settings should come across in the portal template.  Are these all by the same 3rd party, or from different developers?  Perhaps one of the developers is using an uncommon solution for storing settings, but I wouldn't expect that in general.  I do know, however, that portal settings don't get stored in the portal template (so if the modules' settings seem portal-wide in scope, that might be the issue).

Unfortunately, if the settings aren't coming over, there's not much that you can do (you don't be able to force the module to look elsewhere for the settings).  Perhaps if you can find where the settings *are* being stored, you can restore them as a manual after creating the portal, but I doubt that there's a way to include them in the portal template if they aren't coming over naturally.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an inherit limitation in the way that the DotNetNuke template system works.  The actual settings will only be saved if the developer of the module in question stored them in a manner that allows for them to be part of the template.

This is controlled by the way the developer builds their modules and if the modules you are using do not support it, you will not be able to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As Mitchel says, you'll need to manually work out where the affected modules are storing their settings, and come up with a script to propagate those settings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies.

If a module is implementing **Iportable Interface** (*if you see import content/export content in Module settings then that module is implementing Iportable*) and while exporting if you choose "**include content**" module settings are saved to portal template file, otherwise it is not.

thank you all...